# Aligning Divs in a sign up form

Tags: css, html

I wanted to write HTML for a signup form that looks like the one at the following link:

https://www.hipchat.com/sign_up

The issue is, I want to use div tags, ul and li elements to create the form instead of HTML tables. I am having a hard time figuring out how to align the field instructions and the text box inputs using css classes.

Comment: Please show some work u have done.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <label>Name:</label><input class="textbox" type="text" size="30" />
   </li>
</ul>
```

and go on trying some css style, `margin` `float` .......

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use DIVS and LI's?

Use labels and form elements.... Www.w3c.org will help

Answer (score 0):

Here's [something](http://jsfiddle.net/k2AMG/) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Now, my code is very similiar to what you gave. Without entering any information in the sign up form of the link i gave above, Can you hit the sign up button? You will see an error comes up that lines up exactly under the text box. How to modify the CSS to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You would basically do something like this..  strip style from list and float them left.
You can also take out the margin:0 auto; if you don't want it centered.

```
.container {margin: 0 auto; width: 300px;}
.container ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; float: left; width: 50%;}


<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>name</li>
<li>email</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li><input type="text" name="email" /></li>
<li><input type="text" name="email" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form  method="post">
                <div class="field"> 
                    <label for="name">name</label> 
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> 
                </div> <div class="field"> 
                    <label for="email">email</label> 
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> 
                </div> <div class="field"> 
                    <label for="job title">job title</label> 
                    <input id="job title" name="job title" type="text" /> 
                </div> 
                </form>
```

This is much better option use this , don't go for Ul-li use DIV

here is link http://jsfiddle.net/sahil20grover1988/JLbbw/

Comment: I like this, but how can I align field instructions span exactly under the input tag? Press Sign up button on the mentioned link without entering anything to see what i mean

Comment: In that case u can put the button inside another div by making them nested say in div field make one more div align button tofloat left while float the parent div to the right :)

Comment: Please look at my modifications here: http://jsfiddle.net/k2AMG/4/  I want to align the instruction "Please check your name" under the textbox before it.

Comment: Dude go for placeholders instead they are for this purpose